# Formula result shows as 0, but evaluates to the correct value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data on one sheet "Individual Events" that I am referencing on another sheet "Scoreboard".  I am creating a unique ascending list of name values from "Individual Events" on the "Scoreboard" sheet.  My formula is returning **0** as the result, however when I evaluate the formula, I see the correct name value.

[image]

Here is the formula I am using to get the generate the sorted unique name list:

```
={IFERROR(INDEX('Individual Events'!$A$2:$A$501, MATCH(SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,'Individual Events'!$A$2:$A$501)=0, COUNTIF('Individual Events'!$A$2:$A$501, "<"&'Individual Events'!$A$2:$A$501), ""), 1), COUNTIF('Individual Events'!$A$2:$A$501, "<"&'Individual Events'!$A$2:$A$501), 0)),"")}
```

Here is what the Function Arguments window shows as the value:
[image: Formula Arguments Window]

I originally thought this was a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, but that doesn't change the values.

Comment: Weird.... Have you tried the `Formulas` > `Evaluate Formula` toolbar option? Maybe that can help lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Yes - I stepped through and get to =IFERROR("Contenstant Name", "") results in 0.

Comment: @evv_gis The issue is a circular reference with your `COUNTIF` part of your formula here - `IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,'Individual Events'!$A$2:$A$501)=0` The `$A2:A2` is returning the error. I can't pinpoint how to fix it exactly right now, but that's definitely the issue. Notice that if you put this formula in any other cell besides `A2`, you'll get a normal value returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was the circular reference - try this formula:

`={IFERROR(INDEX('Individual Events'!$A$2:$A$501, MATCH(SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,'Individual Events'!$A$2:$A$501)=0, COUNTIF('Individual Events'!$A$2:$A$501, "<"&'Individual Events'!$A$2:$A$501), ""), 1), COUNTIF('Individual Events'!$A$2:$A$501, "<"&'Individual Events'!$A$2:$A$501), 0)),"")}`

You don't want to start at `A2`, you need to start at `A1` to avoid the circular reference.

**EDIT:** Rather, your formula still doesn't really work... I can populate a unique list with this formula just fine, though:

`=INDEX('Individual Events'!$A$2:$A$501,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(Scoreboard!$A$1:A1,'Individual Events'!$A$2:$A$501),0))`